How do you log a message if your Event Template expects a map but doesn't receive a map in log4j2?
I want to be able to use Log4j2 to log in JSON format. I am using JsonTemplateLayout and my own Event Template. My application uses MapMessage when logging so I can extract out values for my log format.
The problem is that not all logs are coming from my source code, some could be from Spring or other libraries that may not be sending a MapMessage.
The problem is that when these libraries are logging without MapMessage my JSON EventTemplate doesn't extract out the message to log.
Full Code Available: https://github.com/LoganDev99/log4j2map
Java Logging Snippet - Log with MapMessage
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Log4j2mapApplication.class, args);

        log.info(new MapMessage<>()
                .with("METHOD", "main()")
                .with("MESSAGE", "My Map Message Event")
        );
    }

log4j2.xml - Using JsonTemplateLayout and additivity false.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:MyLayout.json"/>
        </Console>
        <Console name="DEFAULT_CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <JsonTemplateLayout />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.example" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="WARN">
            <AppenderRef ref="DEFAULT_CONSOLE"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>

MyLayout.json (Event Template) - Using map resolver
{
  "instant": {
    "$resolver": "timestamp",
    "pattern": {
      "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",
      "timeZone": "UTC"
    }
  },
  "message": {
    "$resolver": "map",
    "key": "MESSAGE"
  },
  "method": {
    "$resolver": "map",
    "key": "METHOD"
  }
}

Console Output
{"instant":"2024-10-24T02:06:02.322Z"}
{"instant":"2024-10-24T02:06:02.330Z"}
{"instant":"2024-10-24T02:06:03.461Z"}
{"instant":"2024-10-24T02:06:03.465Z","message":"My Map Message Event","method":"main()"}

Notice how in the first 3 logs there's is no message because in this case it's Spring logging. Spring logs such as "Started Log4j2mapApplication in 1.3 seconds" for example.
So my question is how do have a fallback to just log the message if the message isn't a map.
